# Problems pushing to remote Git repo from Git Gui (windows)

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, ssh

so I have Git GUI installed on windows, and I am wanting to push to a git repository on an ubuntu server.

Here is what I have done so far:

1) Install git

2) Initialise a repository with:

```
mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/gitdir/myproject.git
cd /home/ubuntu/gitdir/myproject.git
git init --bare
```

Now I get a success message saying that this has all worked fine:

```
Initialised empty Git repository in /home/ubuntu/gitdir/myproject.git/
```

When I try to push to the server through Git GUI I get the errors:

```
Url: ubuntu@i.p./home/ubuntu/gitdir/myproject.git
Error: 'link' does not appear to be a git repository. The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

I have also seen some syntax which adds a colon after the IP address, i'm not sure if i'm doing this correctly but it gives an alternate error:

```
Url: ubuntu@i.p.:/home/ubuntu/gitdir/myproject.git/
Error: No supported authentication methods available (error shown via PuTTy popup)
```

I have tried searching for the answer online but can't seem to find anything that works, I just want to get it set up and working then I can finally start learning Git from practice!

Other information:

- My ubuntu server is on amazon EC2. I have a private key to connect via SSH, and I found some information online stating to run pageant.exe in the background with the private key added; this is all set up correctly (as far as I am aware).

If I've missed anything out just ask for more information.

Thanks in advance, Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you intend to use SSH then change the URL to the following:
ssh://ubuntu@i.p:/home/ubuntu/gitdir/myproject.git

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I get the same error via PuTTy prompt: "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available".

Comment: What is your setup in your sshd.conf? Ie that error usually means that it doesn't support passwords and you haven't specified a public key. I would assume that you're using public key auth with password turned off (typically very wise)

Comment: On second look I just made a typo error when try this out, you are correct and I have it working. Thankyou!

Comment: See http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html#pushing and the section on pagant for insutructions for setting up a key.